# Swift - Optional Generic Type

Tags: swift, generics

In Swift, is it possible to make a generic type optional?
For example, I would like to make a generic type `U` optional in the class below.

```swift
class GenericClass<T, U> {
  public var t: T
  public var u: U?

  init(t: T) {
    self.t = t
  }

  init(t: T, u: U) {
    self.t = t
    self.u = u
  }
}

let i1 = GenericClass(t: 1) // Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
let i2 = GenericClass(t: 1, u: "a")
```

I know I can do

```swift
let i1 = GenericClass<Int, Any>(t: 1) // no error
let i2 = GenericClass(t: 1, u: "a")
```

Is there a way to make this work without setting unused type for `U`?

Comment: The compiler still needs to know the concrete type of U, whether it's optional or not. For example, what would you expect to happen if someone did: `i1.u = Foo()`

Comment: here is a proposal to specify default value for parameters in generic clause https://forums.swift.org/t/draft-allow-default-value-for-parameters-in-generic-clause/11200 this way you could have specified default value of `Any` to U and neglect specifying type for U when using `GenericClass(t: 1)`. For now there is no way to do that :D

Comment: @NewDev makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as an unused type. The type system needs to know the type of all variables and if you declare a generic type with 2 generic type parameters, both need to have a type.

Even if the value of `u` is `nil` at the time of `init`, it still needs a specific type, since `Optional` itself is a generic type, so you need to tell the compiler what `Optional<U>` is.

Moreover, unless you make `u` immutable, you cannot guarantee that it will never have a value just by not giving it a value in the `init`. (Actually you do give it a value, it just defaults to `nil`).

So the answer is NO, you cannot instantiate your `GenericClass` without specifying both `T` and `U`.

Answer (score 2):

As [Dávid Pásztor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62026215/6920962) said you can't have unused types.

But you can make hierarchy of generic classes, with each child class having `n+1` generic type variables:

```
class GenericClass1<T> {
    public var t: T

    init(t: T) {
        self.t = t
    }
}

class GenericClass2<T, U>: GenericClass1<T> {
    public var u: U

    init(t: T, u: U) {
        self.u = u
        super.init(t: t)
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let i1 = GenericClass1(t: 1)
let i2 = GenericClass2(t: 1, u: "a")
```

Comment: `GenericClass2` could even wrap a `GenericClass2` button internally, and only contain the differences that depend on `u`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Class can wrap itself? What button?

Comment: Typo: I meant `GenericClass2` could wrap a `GenericClass1`. "What button?" Huh?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, "…wrap a GenericClass2 **button** internally…"

Comment: Ah, I think that was another auto-correction, I don't remember what it was supposed to be. Probably "object", not sure how that got changed lol